# Paired or unpaired median proportion?

Tags: proportion, paired-data

I have measured the presence of a disease (present/absent) in pupils at 10 different schools. Then, disease severity was determined as mild, moderate and severe in those pupils with the disease (the different severity levels are mutually exclusive, which means that one can appear in only one severity category). The proportion of disease (pupils with the disease at school 1 / all pupils at school 1, etc.) was determined as well as the proportion of mild, moderate and severe disease status for each school. Now, I would like to test whether the median proportion of the mild disease status is significantly differnt from the median proportion of the severe disease status. Here are the data:

[image]

In other words, I would like to know whether the median proportion of prop_mild is different from the median proportion of prop_severe. Given that within each school the denominator for each proportion is the same (n_total) but the nominator is different (e.g., n_mild for the proportion of mild disease), I am pretty unsure whether my data are paired or unpaired. My read is, that the data are paired, and I thus need to use a test for paired data (e.g. Wilcoxon signed rank test). Is my presumption right? I really appreciate any hints and suggestions.